# A water molecule is bent. Why?

Tags: bond, valence-bond-theory, bent-bond

Consider the bent shape of $\ce{H2O}$ with a bond angle of $104°$. From my understanding, this is due to the lone pair repulsion between the 2 pairs of lone pair electrons. Hence, it adopts a tetrahedral structure, with a smaller bond angle due to the 2 lone pairs. We know this from VESPR.

However consider the following diagram

[image]

What is inherently wrong with it? To me, it seems that $\ce{H2O}$ could adopt this linear shape without violating any rules. As its symmetrical, the repulsions should essentially cancel each other out, leaving this linear shape. However, obviously this structure is not possible. So what is wrong with it? Why can't the lone pairs be situated on opposite sides as such?

Furthermore, wouldn't placing the lone pairs on opposite sides maximise this distance between them. Hence shouldn't the above be favourable?

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: It's due to the molecular orbitals, the angular spherical $s$ orbitals of the Hydrogen atoms should overlap with two $p$ orbitals in two orthogonal directions, to achieve this geometry the bond cannot be linear otherwise the overlap will only be with one $p$ orbital and the state will be higher in energy.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned that it adopts a tetrahedral. Take a look at this image of a tetrahedral:
[image]

Let's take a look at some possible positions the lone pairs (denoted by purple) can be.
[image][image]
[image]

As you can see, no matter which two places you put the lone pairs, the structure will be identical (they are all the same, just rotated).

So, while it may look like it based on the lewis structure, the lone pairs cannot be on "opposite sides," they will always be next to each other.

Comment: Thing is, in OP's scenario water would be rather "sqare-planar" than tetrahedral.